# Calculating a point position based off a known position from a vector

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces

I'm looking for some help to solve this problem, or just getting pointed to the right area to research into.

I have 3 3D points (A, B, C), which we know the initial positions of.
[initial position of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n2G5.png)

The problem I'm looking to solve is that when points A and C are transformed, how can I calculate the position of B:

[Post transformed points, where B is unknown and needs to be calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VfbL.png)

I've looked into using the vector of AC to find the known angle, but that only gives raidians.

Any suggestions or help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the transformation that you're referring to? The one applied to $A$ and $C$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, we expect the points A, B & C to be transformed together, but only point A and C is known

Comment: So are all the points just moved along the same direction, the same amount? Or how? There's no description of WHAT is happening to the points. Is it a rotation? Or a linear transformation? Or what?

Comment: The points should move in a rigid body fashion, where A, B & C represent the 3D location of the corners of piece of paper as it is being spun.

Comment: So it's only rotation? No translation? Also, do you know if it's rotation about the origin or some other point?

Comment: there might be some translation, but mainly its rotation. all 3 points could be rotated around anywhere

Comment: Okay so certainly the mathematical transformation is of the form
$$
\vec{v}_{\text{new}} = M \vec{v}_{\text{old}} + \vec{s}
$$
where $M$ is a rotation matrix ($\det{M}=1$) and $\vec{s}$ is some constant vector. Next, we need to think about what we could find out about these objects.

Comment: We also know that
$$
\vec{a}_{\text{new}} = M \vec{a}_{\text{old}} + \vec{s}
$$
and 
$$
\vec{b}_{\text{new}} = M \vec{b}_{\text{old}} + \vec{s}
$$
So all of these values are known ...

Comment: Then
$$
\vec{a}_{\text{new}} - \vec{b}_{\text{new}}  = M \left( \vec{a}_{\text{old}}  - \vec{b}_{\text{old}}  \right)
$$
So that's something you could calculate ... Perhaps by this consideration you could find out information about the matrix $M$.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for (I presume) the linear transformation applied, given its effect on two points. Unfortunately in 3-space you need (in general) at least 3 points and their transformation to find this. E.g. two points can move to another two points either through a translation or a rotation about a line.

If, instead, we're looking at 2-space you can find the linear transformation given its effect on two points, and so calculate the position of any other point after transformation. This is done as follows:

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ be our two points, and $(x'_1,y'_1)$ and $(x'_2,y'_2)$ their new positions, respectively. Then,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
y_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_{1} \\
y'_{1}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{2} \\
y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_{2} \\
y'_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is a system of four linear equations in four unknowns.
$$
a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}y_1 = x'_1 \\
a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}y_1 = y'_1 \\
a_{11}x_2 + a_{12}y_2 = x'_2 \\
a_{21}x_2 + a_{22}y_2 = y'_2
$$
or, put another way
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} & y_{1} \\
x_{2} & y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} \\
a_{12}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_{1} \\
x'_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} & y_{1} \\
x_{2} & y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{21} \\
a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
y'_{1} \\
y'_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus you can find the transformation by taking inverses
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} \\
a_{12}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} & y_{1} \\
x_{2} & y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'_{1} \\
x'_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{21} \\
a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} & y_{1} \\
x_{2} & y_{2}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
y'_{1} \\
y'_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Giving you the transformation, which you can then apply to any point.